# "STOP, look, and listen!" alert a bit much?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

I'm not someone who's easily offended, but isn't the "**Stop, look, and listen!**" alert a bit... extreme? Especially when many users have reported "borderline" calls on many of these reviews. The alert makes me feel like I just took down the site or something.

How about a simple, "Oops! Please take another look at the review below to understand why it was closed (or whatever)."?

Comment: I think it should stay how it is. We need to make sure you are paying attention.

Comment: I bet for every borderline audit, there are at least 100 obvious ones. What you see on meta are only the outliers that people complain about.

Comment: It's *supposed* to be a bit much.  The whole reason the user is seeing it is because *they're not paying attention*.

Comment: @Mysticial And even then most of the audits posted on meta are perfectly fine audits.

Comment: @Servy But there's also a temporary audit ban, is there not? It's not like someone is going to ignore the alerts and carry on forever.

Comment: I think it should flash too, and play a nuclear meltdown alarm audio sound.

Comment: @KevinB Well, the audio would help me understand what I'm supposed to be listening to.

Comment: @Bond There are _audio devices_ available, to translate from text to speech for disabled persons (e.g. blind people).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then shouldn't it say, "Stop, look, OR listen."?

Comment: @Bond I think "listen" here is broader than sound... it's a "acknowledge what we are going to tell you"

Comment: @Bond _read_ should probably involved. Don't know how to improve this  for possible analphabetics, getting the message.

Comment: @Bond You're not banned after every single audit, so yes, actually people very much can just keep on reviewing right after an audit ban.  Many would if it's wasn't very noticeable.  Heck, many *already do*.

Comment: @Servy I understand. But there's also a "Next" button that need to be clicked before continuing, which doesn't happen on a successful audit. Edit: Sorry, it does happen on successful audits. I just mean the audit itself stops you temporarily and forces you to focus.

Comment: @Bond Which users just click without thinking when they're robo reviewing, particularly if the UI doesn't make it very clear that they were just caught making a serious mistake.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps. But if they're robo reviewing to the point where they don't notice a button they have to interact with, they're probably not going to notice a message they don't have to interact with.

Comment: @Bond Yes, which is why I specifically said that many people still ignore it even though you're complaining about how "in your face" it is, and despite the fact that *it's goal is to be in your face and to make it as hard as possible to ignore it*.

Comment: @Servy OK, so there's a subset of people who are going to ignore anything you throw at them. We've established that. Then what's the point of catering to them?

Comment: @Bond It's not a boolean value.  It's a spectrum.  Different people will require varying things to actually notice the warning.  The more things that are there, and the more intrusive it is, the more people will notice it.

Comment: I don't get what the discussion is about. I just imagine instead that I'm Vanilla Ice and am reading "_STOP, collaborate, and listen!_"

Comment: @Trobbins - STOP...Hammer time! https://xkcd.com/210/

Comment: [similar request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406228/839601)

Answer (score 8):

> *I'm not someone who's easily offended, but isn't the*
>
> > STOP, look, and listen!
>
> *alert a bit... extreme?*

No it's exactly intended to make you do what you read.

You really should read thoroughly why your decision was declined and you have failed the audit.

> *How about a simple, "Oops! Please take another look at the review below to understand why it was closed (or whatever)."?*

Nope that's not a matter of case, when it's appropriate throwing *cotton balls* on you, but you seriously failed (more than one time before) and should take more attention when reviewing in the future.