# Shouldn't SO "be nice" to reviewers as well?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I understand that SO is very busy being nice to new users.  What about not so new? Ones that achieved access to Review Queue privileges?

While I do think that 2 failed audits in 30 days is too harsh for suspension, my question is about the verbiage that comes with it.

It bluntly accuses the involved member of neglect. We all know that audits are not perfect. Why not to err on the side of civility?

The exact quote:

> We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks.
>
> Poor reviews negatively affect the community.

[Failed First Posts review audits are not cleared after suspension period has ended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407502/failed-first-posts-review-audits-are-not-cleared-after-suspension-period-has-end) post seems to be similar in nature but does not question the very wording.

Bottom line, SO does not really know why members make certain judgement calls during reviews and (in the spirit of nicety) should not immediately assume the worst.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["STOP, look, and listen!" alert a bit much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298840/stop-look-and-listen-alert-a-bit-much)

Comment: Pretty sure there were more recent complaints... but can't find them. I think some even included suggestions for changes. Maybe @Jeanne can use some superior search-fu to find them?

Comment: @yivi But they may already have Roomba'd or got otherwise deleted. But maybe there's still one around.

Comment: My Google Fu found this [deleted one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406228/change-the-tone-and-content-of-the-failed-audit-message-so-its-more-helpful-a), @yivi . (I am honestly surprised it showed up to Google.)

Comment: Points go to @Larnu on this one!

Comment: Dupe on mother meta (because audits are also enabled on other sites, not only on SO anymore): [Audit fail message and our more friendly community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342716/241919).

Comment: Push comes to shove for people that are the target of that message, robo reviewers mostly, the shock is very much intended and necessary. If it doesn't apply to you, well then it is good practice to try and not be bothered by what a static webpage says.